# Converting HTML To PDF using Apache FOP Project within TIBCO BW

Tags: java, apache-fop, html-to-pdf

I'm building a simple process using TIBCO BusinessWork, and trying to convert HTML file to PDF file.

I've downloaded and added Apache FOP as an Alias Library to my project, and wrote the following code:

```
package ProcessDefinition;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory;
import org.apache.fop.apps.Fop;
import org.apache.fop.apps.MimeConstants;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXResult;

public class ProcessDefinitionJavaCode{
/****** START SET/GET METHOD, DO NOT MODIFY *****/
    protected String htmlBinary = "";
    protected String outputPath = "";
    public String gethtmlBinary() {
        return htmlBinary;
    }
    public void sethtmlBinary(String val) {
        htmlBinary = val;
    }
    public String getoutputPath() {
        return outputPath;
    }
    public void setoutputPath(String val) {
        outputPath = val;
    }
/****** END SET/GET METHOD, DO NOT MODIFY *****/
    public ProcessDefinitionJavaCode() {
    }
    public void invoke() throws Exception {
/* Available Variables: DO NOT MODIFY
    In  : String htmlBinary
    In  : String outputPath
* Available Variables: DO NOT MODIFY *****/

FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();

// Step 2: Set up output stream.
// Note: Using BufferedOutputStream for performance reasons (helpful with FileOutputStreams).
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(outputPath)));

try {
    // Step 3: Construct fop with desired output format
    Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, out);

    // Step 4: Setup JAXP using identity transformer
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(); // identity transformer

    // Step 5: Setup input and output for XSLT transformation
    // Setup input stream
    StreamSource src = new StreamSource(new File(htmlPath));

    // Resulting SAX events (the generated FO) must be piped through to FOP
    SAXResult res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

    // Step 6: Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
    transformer.transform(src, res);

} finally {
    //Clean-up
    out.close();
}}
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following exception:

```
BW-JAVA-100001 Job-24000 Error in [Process Definition.process/Java Code]
While executing [invoke] encountered [java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] : [null at org.apache.fop.events.DefaultEventBroadcaster.loadModel(DefaultEventBroadcaster.java:88)]
```

I've made sure i've added all the relevant aliases, and I can't figure what am I missing here.

In addition, the target pdf is created with the following content:

```
%PDF-1.4
%клмн
```

I'm trying to convert the following HTML:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you had a look at DefaultEventBroadcaster.java line 88?

Comment: Looking at this link:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.xmlgraphics/fop/1.1/org/apache/fop/events/DefaultEventBroadcaster.java

I've noticed that line:
return EventModelParser.parse(new StreamSource(in));

Comment: I've attached the simple html I'm trying to convert

Comment: looking at line 88, is the file event-model.xml in your path?

Comment: Hi Astra, no it doesn't.
Where should I include it ? I didn't find that file in ApacheFOP lib.
Should I create it ?

Comment: it may be a red herring but google "fop event-model.xml" and there seems to be a bit of noise around it and it does seem to be the cause of your line 88 problem

Comment: Hi, I think I don't have the "event-model.xml" because I've downloaded "fop-1.1-bin.zip". From what i've seen on the web, "event-model.xml" problem is related to 1.0 vesions only.
BUT, maybe I DO need to download event-model.xml, but where should I put it ? i'm using fop.jar in my project.

Comment: try the same spot as the jar

Comment: tried it. the path is: "ApacheFOP\build" and I'm getting the same error.
I've also tried the root folder "ApacheFOP" and still no change.

Comment: UPDATE:
I found that build:
http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=621037
Which mention that one of the updates is : "Supply missing event-model.xml files".
My problem now is that is a LINUX build and I'm working with Windows environment.

Comment: @ohadinho: Did you manage to solve this issue? I am facing same problem and I am stuck  on that.

Answer (score 0):

A few possible solutions:

1. Downgrade ApacheFOP version (eg one web site said v1.0.16 had the event model xml included)
2. Fix your ApacheFOP version: Get an earlier version that contains the xml file. Find out what directory it is in. Unpack your ApacaheFOP JAR and place the xml in the correct directory, repack
3. Hassle ApacheFOP forum to get the build fixed.